# Plugin diferenciado de auto completar

Tags: autocompletar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]boa tarde,  alguém conhece algum plugin de auto completar que retorne uma quantidade grande de informação do banco de dados, porém no input text exiba apenas um termo?

Comment: Isso é em uma IDE/editor de texto, qual linguaguem?

Comment: Na verdade sou desenvolvedor frontend não utilizarei nenhuma linguagem, preciso criar uma simulação do componente funcionando e repassar o mockup ao pessoal da programação, estes utilizam java.

Comment: @MunirBaarini Pode ilustar melhor a sua dúvida? Como pretende fazer isso sem utilizar nenhuma linguagem? Consegue fazer uma imagem do que você realmente espera que o tal plugin faça?

Comment: Eu tenho uma imagem, como faço para exibi-la aqui?

Comment: Mas "plugin" é algo que você pluga em outra coisa... que coisa é essa? InDesign? Dreamweaver? Outro? . . . É só usar o botão de inserir imagem no editor, ou então postar o link que algum outro usuário insere ela.

Comment: o plugin deve ser inserido no html. A imagem exemplifica como deve ser, após pesquisar uma ncm (código em negrito) são exibidas diversas informações sobre a mesma, não somente um ou dois termos como é comum nos recursos de autocomplete.